# When sharing a link to facebook, why do I get a small thumbnail?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, sharing

Whenever I share a link from my site on facebook, I get a small thumbnail image of the product, and a title and description. I upload my own, bigger photo (1200x630) (that is the recommended size) to the shared link, and I still get small thumbnail images.

Why can't I get a large image when I share a link? On other business pages, I see it all the time.

I got it to work once, but then, using the exact same process, I tried again, and it went back to the small thumbnail.

Thanks,
Chad

Comment: what method are you using to 'share' it?

Comment: I've noticed that I often get small image on newsfeed and larger image on timeline.  are you seeing it differently in different places?  With open graph, I know that I have to use a flag called explicitly_shared

Comment: I'm just posting the link as a status. I am not sure what open graph is or how to use it.

Comment: is there a difference between viewing it on the timeline vs the news feed?

Comment: No, but I have 1 post that is how I want it (with the large picture). They show up differently on my timeline (the large picture one and the new ones that I'm posting)